Relation between short term rate and forward rates
I'm trying to understand relationship between short rates and forward rates
Let $f(t,T)$ is forward rates compounding at $T$ as seen from $t$, and $r(t)$ just a short rate
For a Zero Coupon Bond paying \$1 at maturity $T$ following relations holds:
$$P(t,T) = e^{-\int_t^Tf(t,s)ds}$$
$$P(t,T) = E[e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds}|\mathcal{F}_t]$$
Can we say that forward rates is conditional expectations of short rates?
$$f(t,T) = E[r(T)|\mathcal{F}_t]$$
Does it holds under special assumption if not?

Think of it. Is $e^{-x}$ a function that commutes with the expectation?

@kurtg already ... even tried to expand ln(P(t,T)) as Taylor series, but expectations of powers of integrals is too much for me :( could you recommend some articles to clarify relation between forward and short rates? specifically if i have forward rates what can i say about implied/expected short rate dynamics?

To get $f(t,T)$ from $P(t,T)$ you differentiate $-\ln P(t,T),.$ To get $r(t)$ from $f(t,T)$ you set $r(t)=f(t,t),.$ More explicit relationships can be obtained when the model for $r(t)$ allows for a closed form solution of $P(t,T,r(t))$ (Markovian short rate models). The prime examples are Vasicek, generalized Hull White, CIR. See the book of Musiela and Rutkowski.
